# Hide frame, progress bar and buttons from Youtube film

Tags: php, jquery, html, youtube

At a page I am showing a Youtube film in a lightbox.

I then want to show only the raw video film - no controls, play/pause buttons, fullscreen option, progress bar etc.
Right now it looks like this:

[image: Youtube example]

and I simply need to remove the top and bottom flash bars with icons. I know it slides away while the films is running, but I wish to always have them hidden.

Is this possible to hide from the film?

**Update**

From the answer from @Sven below I added `controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0` to the URL in the `iframe` and got the following:

[image: Youtube example 2]

This works fine for the purpose. It seems though that a Youtube logo is visible in the lower right corner instead when this other stuff is removed. This logo is only shown at hover.

Any ideas to hide this last bit?

Comment: can you do it with JavaScript? Example: reddit.com/r/starcraft/comments/2hq22j/hide_youtube_progress_bar_to_avoid_time_spoilers/

Comment: Just wondering how 'php' and 'jquery' this question is related. HTML and YouTube is fine, but 'php'? Really?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Depending on how you are inserting the video, there are several configuration options. 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

If you insert the link directly as an iframe most of the options work as `GET` parameters. In your case add `controls=0&showinfo=0` to the video url.

Comment: Super, thanks. Can the Youtube logo in the lower right corner also be removed? (It seems that a half transparent logo appears at hover if those other bars are removed).

Comment: Yep, via `modestbranding=1`.

Comment: Hmm that didn't work. I now use this: `autoplay=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&modestbranding=1`. The result can be seen in my update to the question above. And that `modestbranding=1` makes no difference.

Comment: Oh, you are right. The option `modestbranding=1` only removes the logo in the control panel.